# Issue calling player.togglePlay() in Spotify Web Player

Tags: reactjs, spotify

When I try to call player.togglePlay() as described in the Spotify Web Player API, I get an error
"caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'togglePlay')"

However, I check immediately before that line in the console, and player is not null. I even checked its keys to ensure that it had a method named togglePlay, which it does. Weirdly enough, if I change that line to call player.connect() or player.addListener(), I do not get an error.

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
      if (props.token !== '' && player === null) {
        const player = new window.Spotify.Player({
          name: 'Web Playback SDK',
          getOAuthToken: (cb: (token: string) => void) => {
            cb(props.token)
          },
          volume: 0.5,
        })

        setPlayer(player)

        player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }: any) => {
          player.togglePlay()
          console.log('Ready with Device ID', device_id)
        })
```